# error when building veins_inet: unexpected token

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, inet

I have a Windows 10 PC where I installed Veins 5.0 following the tutorial and therefore I have installed OMNeT++ 5.6.1. I have also INET 4.2.0 that has been installed after opening the OMNeT IDE for the first time. I can open successfully the simulations from OMNeT++, Veins and INET. Nevertheless, when it comes to build the veins_project of veins/subprojects I get the following error:

```
10:48:52 **** Incremental Build of configuration gcc-release for project veins_inet ****
make MODE=release all 
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/src/veins-veins-5.0/subprojects/veins_inet/src'
veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.cc
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `clang++ -c -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG=1 -MMD -MP -MF ../out/clang-release/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.o.d    -isystem /usr/include -isystem /mingw64/include -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-unused-function -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -DXMLPARSER=libxml -DPREFER_QTENV -DWITH_QTENV -DWITH_PARSIM -DWITH_NETBUILDER -DWITH_OSG -DWITH_OSGEARTH -DVEINS_INET_EXPORT  -DINET_IMPORT -DVEINS_IMPORT -DVEINS_INET_EXPORT -I"C:/src/veins-veins-5.0/subprojects/veins_inet/src" -I"C:/src/veins-veins-5.0/src" -I"C:/src/inet4/src" -I. -IC:/Universidad/2019-2020 (Master)/1B - Quadrimestre Primavera/TFM/OMNET/inet/src -IC:/src/veins-veins-5.0/src -I. -IC:/src/omnetpp-5.6.1/include -o ../out/clang-release/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.o veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.cc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:153: ../out/clang-release/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/src/veins-veins-5.0/subprojects/veins_inet/src'
make: *** [Makefile:36: all] Error 2
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

10:48:53 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 942ms)
```

Does anyone experience something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear the problem is in your command line

```
clang++ -c -std=c++11 ... -IC:/Universidad/2019-2020 (Master)/1B  ...
```

Don't put parentheses or spaces in folder names. It's only likely to lead to confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was this problem.